# Compile Hadoop native library failed on mac

Tags: macos, hadoop

I am trying to compile the hadoop native library on mac os.

My Mac OS X is 10.7.4. My Hadoop is 1.0.3

I have installed the zlib 1.2.7 and lzo 2.0.6 like below:
./configure -shared --prefix=/usr/local/[zlib/lzo]
make
make install

I change the .bash_profile like below

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/zlib-1.2.7/include:/usr/local/lzo-2.06/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/zlib-1.2.7/lib:/usr/local/lzo-2.06/lib
export CFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

I switch to hadoop folder and run

```
ant -Dcompile.native=true compile-native
```

I got such information like below

```
[exec] checking stddef.h usability... yes
     [exec] checking stddef.h presence... yes
     [exec] checking for stddef.h... yes
     [exec] checking jni.h usability... yes
     [exec] checking jni.h presence... yes
     [exec] checking for jni.h... yes
     [exec] checking zlib.h usability... yes
     [exec] checking zlib.h presence... yes
     [exec] checking for zlib.h... yes
     [exec] checking Checking for the 'actual' dynamic-library for '-lz'... 
     [exec] configure: error: Can't find either 'objdump' or 'ldd' to compute the dynamic library for '-lz'

BUILD FAILED
```

Does anyone meet this issue before?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There was a JIRA ([3659](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3659)) ticket submitted for this - you should be able to take the top patch file and apply it. Read the comment thread though, as there is some talk about it not supporting 32bit.

Comment: Hi, I use the hadoop 1.0.3, it seems for hadoop 0.20, the patch file can't be patched. Anyway, I manually edit the acinclude.m4 file. It works, the error disappear. However, there is another error come out. It can't find the java header file. I have set the JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home, however, there is no such include folder under it. Have you meet it before?